# Issues connecting to more than one oracle datasource using grails

Tags: database, oracle, grails, datasource

If this is a duplicate, please forgive me. I have searched and searched. But I have something that's been bugging me for the past couple of days. I have researched and haven't found a solution that solves my issues. I'm working on an application that will need to access multiple databases. If I do just one database and inject it into the code with a datasource object, it does just fine with whatever database I use. But if I try to add another datasource, that's when the problems start. I have tried adding the configuration to datasource.groovy and I've tried 'hardcoding' the connection.

**Hardcode method**

As you can see, I've tried using the various methods below and ALL have given me the error following. The ojdbc6.jar loads correctly, because I have verified by deliberately misspelling the driver class name and got the class not found error.

```
import java.sql.*

def index(){
    ...
    def db = [url:'jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com', user:'other_user', password:'other_pw', driver:'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver']
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
    //      Sql.loadDriver("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    //      Sql.loadDriver("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
    //      def sql2 = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com','other_user','other_pw','oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
    //      def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com", "other_user", "other_pw", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
    //      DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver())
    //      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    //      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com','other_user','other_pw')
    //      Sql sql = new Sql(conn)
    ...
}
```

error:

```
Error |
2014-10-28 11:38:06,766 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /ApplicationPortal/home
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
   Line | Method
->> 602 | getConnection in java.sql.DriverManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   185 | getConnection in     ''
|   192 | index . . . . in com.myapp.HomeController$$EOu0LeDV
|   200 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   895 | runTask       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . in     ''
^   662 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

**Datasource.groovy configuration method**

I have tried different configurations in datasource.groovy. Currently this is what it looks like:

```
dataSource {
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    pooled = true
    properties {
        maxActive = -1
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
        numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
        testOnBorrow=true
        testWhileIdle=true
        testOnReturn=true
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"
    }
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    showsql = true
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@database.whatever.com"
            username="data_user"
            password = "some_pw"
        }
        dataSource_task {
            url = "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com"
            username="other_user"
            password = "other_pw"
        }
    }

}
```

And I'm getting the error. I don't know why it's trying to use the h2 database. I need it to connect to the oracle database.

```
Error |
2014-10-29 13:30:53,500 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.h2.Driver@42b1b290 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-10-29 13:30:53,547 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.h2.Driver@2d2c1472 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-10-29 13:30:53,621 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-10-29 13:30:53,634 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_task' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties_task' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector_task' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector_task': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_task' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties_task' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector_task' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector_task': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties_task' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector_task' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector_task': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties_task': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector_task' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector_task': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector_task': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@17898b92 returned null for URL:jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Setup:
Grails 2.3.7
Oracle 11g

**EDIT:**
The problem with the datasource method is not with how many datasources I use. I has to do with the name. If I just use one datasouce as datasource_other, it will throw the error. But datasource works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the datasource configuration method is concerned, I figured that one. It was a boneheaded mistake. I didn't add the driverClassName to the dataSource_task.

```
dataSource_task {
    url = "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@someotherdatabase.whatever.com"
    username="other_user"
    password = "other_pw"
    driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'// <- it needed this
}
```

I'd still like to know why the hardcode method doesn't work tho.