# java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:/data/sample;IFEXISTS=TRUE

Tags: spring, maven, h2

**Disclaimer**: Spring-boot noob.

I'm trying to set up an H2 database for integration testing with spring-boot.

I'm getting error: `java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver@2e179f3e returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:/data/sample;IFEXISTS=TRUE`

I'm not really sure what to do here.
I have to override `spring.datasource.url` because that value is expected to be in the app.

### FirstTest.groovy

```
package com.api

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Api.class)
@IntegrationTest(value = "spring.profiles.active=h2")
@Slf4j
class FirstTest {


    @Test
    void test() {
        log.info 'debug log statement'
    }

}
```

### src/test/resources/config/application-h2.properties

```
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/data/sample;IFEXISTS=TRUE
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=H2
```

### pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.189</version>
</dependency>
...
```

---

**EDIT:** This post: [spring boot default H2 jdbc connection (and H2 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655684/spring-boot-default-h2-jdbc-connection-and-h2-console) seemed to answer my question

### src/test/resources/config/application-h2.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:foo-database;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to explicitly set the JDBC driver class name, as you did in the other definition:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver // <== add this
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/data/sample;IFEXISTS=TRUE
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=H2
```

See also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639300/issues-connecting-to-more-than-one-oracle-datasource-using-grails).